# Cannot implicitly convert type short to Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot initialize this data:

```
NewUpload.Currency = Convert.ToInt16(data.Rows[i]["Currency"]);
```

because i've got an error.

I have this model structure:

```
public Currency Currency { get; set; }
```

How will i resolve this error? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the value of `data.Rows[i]["Currency"]`?

Comment: The value is integer.

Comment: See the 2nd code snippet in the accepted answer of the dupe.

Comment: when i tried this one, Currency currency = (Currency)data.Rows[i]["Currency"];

Comment: i've got error: inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: No, you still need to convert to `int` first, then to `enum`. - e.g. `int currency = Convert.ToInt16(data.Rows[i]["Currency"]); NewUpload.Currency = (Currency)currency;`

Comment: Yes, I already did but error still persist: inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Which is a different issue. Is the `enum` defined as public?

Comment: Yes, got it. thanks for the help.